# PHP method calls from Javascript not showing up in Wordpress source

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am running a Wordpress website, and trying to call PHP methods from my Javascript code.

When a button is tapped, the `saverFoo()` Javascript method is called, and attempts to call the PHP method `save_image_data()`.

```
      function saverFoo() {
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
        <?php echo save_image_data(dataURL); ?>;
      }

      function loaderFoo() {  
        var loadedImage = <?php echo loadimagedata(); ?>;
        console.log(loadedImage);
      }
```

The PHP method's implementation is in the `function.php` file, and is simply attempting to save some image data (dataURL) in the user's meta

```php
    function save_image_data($imageData) {
       global $current_user;
       update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'user_design', $_POST['$imageData']);
    } 

     function loadimagedata() {
       global $current_user;
       $old_notes = get_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'user_design', true);
       return $old_notes;
     }
```

Inspecting my web-page in Chrome, shows me an empty space where `loaderFoo ()` (javascript) is supposed to be calling `loadimagedata()` (php) , and `loadedImage` is an undefined variable, when I try to log it, such as:

```
      function loaderFoo() {  
        var loadedImage = ;
        console.log(loadedImage);
      }
```

Not sure what fundamental mistake I'm making here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always remember that PHP runs on the server side, and javascript on the client side. So we have an order here, the server receives the request PHP processes what it should process and render the page, only here Javascript will be executed.

In this example, when the 'saverFoo()' function is executed, this function `<? Php echo save_image_data (dataURL); ?>;` has already been written on the page. PHP will not be able to get the information contained in the `dataURL` variable, not on this way. To do this, we must make a request to the server with this desired information, but with an "image" is not trivial to do this, as there is a limit on the size of the post when using a normal String field.

```
function saverFoo () {
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL ();
    <? php echo save_image_data (dataURL); ?>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP doesn't work that way.  It is a pre-processor.  It is all run and done server side and the resulting text/html/binary data/whatever is sent out to the client.  In the case of a content type of `text/html` the browser will load it, parse it, render it, and run whatever javascript is called.

How you can mix PHP and JavaScript in-line like that would be to use PHP to fill in variables.  For example

```
alert("<?php print($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']); ?>");
```

would work because the client would see

```
alert("/path/to/foo.php");
```

and render that for the user.

To really interact with PHP using JavaScript, you'll want to look into using a http based REST type service and perhaps one of the various popular tool sets like Angular, Vue, etc.